# Trigger NSNotification when opening specific https URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to trigger a notification with `NSNotificationCenter` when a specific https URL is opened within my App. I have tried the following in my **AppDelegate's** `application:openURL:options:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {

  if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
    NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openHTTPSLinkNotification" object:url];
    return YES;
  } if ([[url scheme] hasPrefix:@"https"]) {
    NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openHTTPSLinkNotification" object:url];
    return YES;
  } else if ([[url resourceSpecifier] isEqualToString:@"//www.dummylink.com/"]) {
        NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"openHTTPSLinkNotification" object:url];
        return YES;
    } else
      return NO;
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the Swift Class that Initializes the NSNotificationCenter and also opens a Safari View

```
import SafariServices

let openHTTPSLinkNotification = "openHTTPSLinkNotification"

let accessUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.dummylink.com")


class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    var safariVC: SFSafariViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: accessUrl!)
        safariVC!.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(safariVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.safariLogin(_:)), name: openHTTPSLinkNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func safariLogin(notification: NSNotification) {
        let url = notification.object as! NSURL
        self.safariVC!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have also configured the URL scheme as followed in my Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.testapp.ios</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>www.dummylink.com</string>
            <string>https</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But it never seems to trigger no matter what I change.

**EDIT:** If I define a URL scheme that opens another app via its custom URL on my phone it will open that app and trigger the application:openURL:options: function

How can I trigger a notification when I open a https link like https://www.dummylink.com
? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: For that at least once your `NSNotificationCenter ` should initialize.

Comment: Then in your code which class is registering this code? And if you trigger it in AppDelegate, make sure that class is initialized

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I added the Swift class that initializes NSNotificationCenter to the question.